# With the new music update, is it possible to play the "loud" music during stealth?

Tags: payday-2

As stated in the title, with the release of the Big Music Update, is there any way to play the music that would play during a loud heist while still in stealth rather than the stealth music?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not within the game, no. It will only start the music when things go loud. However, you can use the Steam Music Player<sup>1</sup> from the in-game overlay to play that music, if you haven't moved it out of the default location within the game's installation folder.

<sup>1</sup>may or may not require you to join the official Steam Music group